# Using Apache ActiveMQ + XMPP over plain XMPP for messaging

Tags: java, xmpp, messaging, activemq-classic, openfire

I am producing a message passing system and considering using [ActiveMQ with XMPP](http://activemq.apache.org/xmpp.html) as the transport. I have used plain XMPP with [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) server for similar messaging based communication between distributed parts of a system. What would be the advantage of layering ActiveMQ on top of XMPP, given the built in Jabber server in Apache ActiveMQ is nowhere as neat and extensible out of the box as the Openfire Jabber server.

Question 1) Can I replace the built-in Jabber server with Openfire and still use ActiveMQ ?

All the client and server components are going to be in Java and I have used the Openfire Xmpp (Spark) libraries in the past.

Question 2) What will the attraction of ActiveMQ for brokering XMPP

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ dropped support for XMPP a few releases ago so you probably won't find any advantage to using it in this manner.  The XMPP support was not very well implemented and never got a lot of use.